# How to create a transparent region (div) over semi-transparent background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a 'magnifying lens' ui for a web page. Anything on the page directly below the lens should be visible, while everything else should be made semi-transparent. In other words, I want to create a semi-transparent layer (which blocks the entire page) with a transparent 'hole' (lens) in it. I should be able to move the lens around, and possibly, resize the lens as well. I have thought of a solution that involves covering the entire page with 3x3 divs, making all the divs semi-transparent except for the middle one which will host the lens and will be completely transparent. I would then handle resize & move of the lens-div (and other divs around it) in javascript. I am looking for alternate, simpler solutions to this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your lens can be a square, or you want it to be round as possible?

Comment: It can be a rectangle. But it should resize & move. Thanks!

Comment: Then you can achieve it with simply four divs, that would delimit a rectangular region. I had to do something similar. In my case, I had to let my users select an article in a list, and block everything else except that article. Unfortunately, I won't be to share what I did until tomorrow. I don't feel like rewriting the code, though there aren't a lot of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question! Consider this simplified implementation:

```
var $helperLeft = $('.helper-left'),
    $helperRight = $('.helper-right'),
    $helperTop = $('.helper-top'),
    $helperBottom = $('.helper-bottom'),

$view = $('.view').draggable({
    drag: onDrag
}),
viewWidth = $view.width(),
viewHeight = $view.height();

function onDrag(event, ui) {
    $helperLeft.css({width: ui.position.left});
    $helperRight.css({left: ui.position.left + viewWidth});
    $helperTop.css({
        width: viewWidth,
        left: ui.position.left,
        height: ui.position.top
    });
    $helperBottom.css({
        top: ui.position.top + viewHeight,
        left: ui.position.left,
        width: viewWidth
    });
}

onDrag(null, {position: $view.position()});
```

That's it! Very short and simple. I think resizing is straightforward too.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j74A9/

Comment: Thanks! Very short and simple indeed!! I could get the resize code working. Here it is: [http://jsfiddle.net/j74A9/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/j74A9/1/)